# can I have a parsys inside parsys

Tags: java, html, css, content-management-system, aem

I'm having a paragraph system (parsys) in my page, and inside that I'm dragging one component; that component has two paragraph systems inside it. So now I will be dragging a rich text component in both of the two paragraph systems which are present in the component. However, after dragging the rich-text components in the two paragraph systems, I'm not able to edit the those two rich text components, as they got overlapped. Can you tell me whether we can have a parsys inside a parsys and will that support content authoring.

Comment: That's how the column control works, it's parsys inside parsys. IIRC there's properties that need to be set on the inner component; 'container'? Something like that. Anyhow, maybe it's a CQ setting or maybe it's a CSS issue that makes them overlap and unedittable. How do they behave if you add them to Geometrixx?

Comment: Yes, correct, it is the issue with css,we can make those parsys not to overlap by giving padding-top:some value to the inner parsys which makes the inner parsys come out of the outer parsys,thank you Antonyh

Comment: There were some issues like the one you mention with nested parsys, but since CQ 5.4 they should be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have a parsys inside a parsys. The overlapping problem would be a CSS issue, and can be solved most of the time by adding the following div at the end of your component code.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Also, to prevent adding additional div styles to your page, this should be done only in author mode:

```
<% if (WCMMode.fromRequest(request) == WCMMode.EDIT) { %>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
<% } %>
```